# Disable auto font-kerning for firefox and ie10?

Tags: css, firefox, typography, internet-explorer-10, kerning

How do you disable auto font-kerning for firefox and ie10? I've spent a while trying to search for a solution but all I get are out dated pages and experimental methods.

Comment: This should not have been closed. It might be a duplicate, but not off-topic – this is about CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Previously, on Firefox, setting `text-rendering: optimizeSpeed` in CSS prevented kerning (and ligatures). According to [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-rendering), such a setting is now ignored “because the standard code for text rendering is already very fast and there is not a faster code path at this time”.

You can prevent kerning by using a font to which the browser does not apply kerning at all. The documentation is vague, but it seems that Firefox applies kerning to some “C fonts” by Microsoft and to DejaVu fonts.

Another, very clumsy, way is to use ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER (U+200C) characters between letters, e.g. `W&zwnj;ally` to have “Wally” rendered without kerning the “Wa” pair.

Comment: does not work at all, and so as this http://stackoverflow.com/q/12919393/104380 does not work.

Comment: I've tried putting a zero width character after every normal one, but it seems the kerning is powerful and wise that such conjury would only help a little.