# Kerning on font between chrome and firefox

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, kerning

I am working on a menu with a custom font and in chrome (and safari) it is spaced exactly how I want it.

http://american-motorsports.net/2012/

When I view it in firefox, the kerning of the font is a little different causing a little black gap on the far right menu item. I can see the difference between the **F** and **A** in **FABRICATION**

The HTML is very simple right now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/main.css" />
<title><?php echo date('M d, Y') . ' | '; ?>American Motorsports - Off-Road Fabrication</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="resources/images/logo.png" width="291" height="150" alt="American Motorsports - Off-Road Fabrication" />
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
            <a href="#"><span class="item">HOME</span></a><a href="#"><span class="item">SUSPENSION</span></a><a href="#"><span class="item">FABRICATION</span></a><a href="#"><span class="item">PROJECTS</span></a><a href="#"><span class="item">MEDIA</span></a><a href="#"><span class="item">CONTACT</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS consists of this so far

```
@font-face {  
    font-family: bebas;  
    src: url("../fonts/bebas.ttf") format("truetype");  
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ccc;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url("../images/bg.png") #202020;
}

#wrap {
    background: url("../images/bg_main.jpg") no-repeat center top;
    min-height:800px;
}

#header {
    border-top: 5px solid #3a3a3a;
    height:150px;
    width:970px;
    background-color:#000000;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

#logo {
    width:324px;
    height:179px;
    background-color:#121212;
    border-top: 5px solid #3a3a3a;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ffffff;
    margin-top:-22px;
    float:left;
}

#logo img {
    margin-left:13px;
    margin-top:17px;
}

#menu {
    width:646px;
    height:150px;
    float:right;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
}

#menu a {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.item {
    font-family:bebas;
    font-size:18px;
    height:150px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:8em;
    color:#fff;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    margin:0;
    text-shadow: 0 3px 3px #111;
}

.item:hover {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #3a3a3a 0%, #101010 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#3a3a3a), color-stop(100%,#101010));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #3a3a3a 0%,#101010 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #3a3a3a 0%,#101010 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #3a3a3a 0%,#101010 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #3a3a3a 0%,#101010 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3a3a3a', endColorstr='#101010',GradientType=0 );
}

#main {
    width:970px;
    /*background-color:#ffffff;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

So the question is how to remove the gap so it looks like chrome and safari or fix the kerning issue..I just dont want that gap in firefox

Comment: FYI, the gap still exists in Safari (at least on iOS devices).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick dirty solution is

```
#menu{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden; /* means you don't get a dirty edge, but the last link may be smaller on the right */
}
```

Ideally though, you shouldn't be relying on the width of the font to make your menu look right.
If you have the time, give each of these links a class, and a custom width.
Or even better, use a list with links in each item, to get greater control.

For example, if you add:

```
.item{
  padding: 0;
  width: 16.66%; /* assuming you always have 6 links */
}
```

...they will always fit, but some will look rubbish.
For the most professional-looking finish, you'll want to give each a class and custom width.

Comment: yeah, making individual classes would definitely work, I want to make it as dynamic as possible if I can. I may have to do this

Comment: I ended up giving each menu item its own class and manually setting the width and it is now consistent across all browsers `.menuOne {width:80px}
.menuTwo {width:130px}
.menuThree {width:134px}
.menuFour {width:112px}
.menuFive {width:85px}
.menuSix {width:105px}`

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to wrap a `span` around the offending letters and tweak the CSS `letter-spacing:` property until you get what you want.

The finesse of good typography, especially when it comes to custom fonts, isn't quite ready for prime-time on browsers.

**Plan B**: use an image.

Comment: yeah this is my first time using custom fonts. I've thought of using images but if I don't have to, that'd be awesome. I'm going to try what you suggested with letter-spacing. I'll report back, thanks!

Comment: I could make it larger, but not smaller with the letter-spacing so I went the route of giving each menu item a class and defining the width

Answer (score 0):

I don’t see what gap you are trying to remove, but what you are describing is the issue that Firefox (modern versions) apply kerning by default, if defined in a font. Other browsers don’t. So it’s a matter of kerning vs. no kerning, not a difference in kerning. Kerning is generally considered as typographically desirable. But if you really want to prevent Firefox from kerning, that’s possible using [font feature settings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font-feature-settings), e.g. in this case with

```
#menu  { -moz-font-feature-settings: "kern" 0; }
```

Comment: I've uploaded the fix already which is why you don't see it. I'm going to try this right now as well though

Comment: Hmm, didn't seem to make a difference. I tried it on the menu div as well as the `item` class which are the menu items

Comment: I have uploaded the latest version to the link I posted in my OP. It's now working though

Comment: @vsync, your comment is about your use of another font, in a messy context. If you have a problem with it, you should ask a question of your own, explain the problem (“does not work” is not a description), and reduce the issue to the smallest possible demo case.

Comment: This makes no difference for me with Firefox 32, Linux, using a font from Google Fonts. I.e. the text width in Firefox did not change, and is still different to how it appears in Chrome (Chrome is more spaced out). Shame, as this looked like it would be the solution!

Comment: @DarrenCook, it makes no difference if the font has no kerning table (in a format that the browser can read). Please consider asking a new question, with sufficient detail, and explaining what the problem really is. Note that font rendering generally varies across platforms and browsers, quite independently of kerning issues too.